# WPF UserControl DesignMode property (Hosted on a WinForm)

Tags: wpf, designer

I search `DesignMode` boolean on a custom WPF UserControl... How **correctly** do I impelment it?

I have a WPF Control **hosted in a WinForm**. I saw that the "DesignerProperties" class does not work in such a case.

I have some logic in the constructor that throws exceptions in the design mode and want to skip that code, because I don't arrive to see a Form with my UserControl in the designer.

I tried

```
private static bool? _isInDesignMode;

/// <summary>
/// Gets a value indicating whether the control is in design mode 
/// (running in Blend or Visual Studio).
/// </summary>
public static bool IsInDesignModeStatic
{
    get
    {
        if (!_isInDesignMode.HasValue)
        {
#if SILVERLIGHT
    _isInDesignMode = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool;
#else
            var prop = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;
            _isInDesignMode
                = (bool)DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                .FromProperty(prop, typeof(FrameworkElement))
                .Metadata.DefaultValue;
#endif
        }

        return _isInDesignMode.Value;
    }
}
```

but this does not work :(( I see designer exceptions at "blocked" with IsInDesignModeStatic code lines...

Answer (score 2):

I used this to detect DesignMode (my WPF control is defined in a Class Library).

```
    ' Exit here if in Design Mode
    If Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

You may be able to check Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.FullName.ToString if it is not nothing and determine where the control is being initialized from.

The DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty was returning null for me when the control was hosted in WinForms because WPF doesn't know there is a designer there.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this/*this user control*/))
    {
        // Design-mode specific functionality
    }
```

Comment: does not work, designer gives me a stacktrace with an error from inside the if(!DesignerProperties....)

Comment: I should remark that I have a winForm and inside a WPF control, this code does not work for the WPF control when I open the Winform